# Why am I receiving this error when sorting a Text file by a certain column based upon number?

Tags: python, file-io, output

My code for the sorting of the file.

```
g = open('Lapse File.txt', 'r')
column = []
i = 1
next(g)
for line in g:  
    column.append(int(line.split('\t')[2]))

column.sort()
```

This is the error I get.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Owles/new lapse .py", line 51, in <module>
    column.append(int(line.split('\t')[2]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-8.3\n
```

My main question is why is there a \n. Earlier in the code I had written to another text file and wrote it by column from a previously read in file. 
This is my code for writing the file

```
for columns in (raw.strip().split() for raw in Sounding):
if (i >2 and i <=33):
    G.write(columns [3]+'\t'+columns[2]+'\t'+columns[4]+'\n')
    i = i + 1
elif (i >= 34):
    G.write(columns [0]+'\t'+columns[1]+'\t'+columns[2]+'\n')
    i = i + 1
else:
    i = i + 1
```

I am unsure if writing the lines like that is the issue because I have inserted the new line function.

Comment: Have you seen [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes, but I am trying to utilize just in the text file in order to save time for converting hundreds of original files to csv format.

Comment: Did you take a good look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Because only numeric strings can be cast to integers; look at this:

```
numeric_string = "109"
not_numeric_string = "f9"
```

This is okay:

```
>>> int(numeric_string)
109
```

And it cannot be cast:

```
>>> int(not_numeric_string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f9'
```

So somewhere in your script it is getting a non-numeric string.
It seems as though the "-8.3\n" string sequence has raised the error, so you must strip escape chars as well.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback is telling you exactly what happened:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-8.3\n'
```

The problem here is that, while `int()` can handle the negative sign and the trailing newline character, it can't handle the decimal point, `'.'`. As you know, `-8.3` may be a real, rational number, but it's not an integer. If you want to preserve the fractional value to end up with `-8.3`, use `float()` instead of `int()`. If you want to discard the fractional value to end up with `-8`, use `float()` to parse the string and then use `int()` on the result.

`-8.3`:

```
column.append(float(line.split('\t')[2]))
```

`-8`:

```
column.append(int(float(line.split('\t')[2])))
```